# trigger onmouseover function without hover but click on the other div

Tags: javascript, css, triggers, onmouseover

I want to know how to trigger the `onmouseover` function by clicking on the other `div`. I like it to be done by only JavaScript. Here is the code:

```js
function showBlue() {
    document.getElementById('xyz').style.background = "#425dff"; 
}
function showRed() {
    document.getElementById('xyz').style.background = "#b43700";
}
```

```css
#abc {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#xyz {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #e2e2e2;
}
```

```html
<div id="abc"><a>click me</a></div>

</br>

<div id="xyz" onmouseover="showBlue()" onmouseout="showRed()"></div>
```

**What I've tried, but didn't work:**

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('abc').addEventListener("click", triggerFunction);

    function triggerFunction {
        document.getElementById('xyz').onmouseover();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to fire the event on the element, just execute the function directly like this:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('abc').addEventListener('click', triggerFunction);

    function triggerFunction {
        showBlue();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @DylanDaicySiao Do you mind setting up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) reproducing the issue? It will help us to identify the issue.

Comment: What I like to know is to programmatically trigger the onmouseover event in plain JavaScript instead of placing another function inside the function.